# Scientific Linux 6 assigning keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, scientific-linux

Can I assign keyboard shortcuts for launching Konsole terminal emulator on Scientific Linux 6 without administrator privileges?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using, KDE?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Yes I am using the KDE.